# Install TensorFlow 2.2 or 2.3 on offline Windows 7 computer using conda-pack

Tags: anaconda, windows-7, conda, offline

I have a computer with Windows 7.  The computer is offline.  I would like to use TensorFlow 2.2 or 2.3 on it, as well as the rest of Anaconda packages.

I've tried a few things, but I think the best idea I had was:

```
 1) Install Anaconda on another online Windows 7 machine
 2) Install TensorFlow 2.3 using pip (b/c I only see conda supporting up to Tensorflow 2.1 currently)
 3) Use conda-pack
```

This seems to cause some issues b/c conda-pack complains about pip deleting/removing some files.

Is the process I outlined above in steps 1-3 the correct approach or is there a better way to get Anaconda tools with TensorFlow 2.2 or 2.3 onto an offline Windows 7 computer?

Comment: Maybe [`conda-constructor`](https://github.com/conda/constructor) would be the better tool for this. It'll bundle everything into an installer.

Comment: How about downloading the tensorflow whl file and then installing it with pip on the offline machine

Comment: @FlyingTeller does the TensorFlow whl file include all the TensorFlow dependencies too?  Do you know if the whl files are Windows version dependent (i.e. will the same TensorFlow whl work on Windows 7 and Windows 10)?